# Find all possible values for the dimension of W

Tags: linear-algebra

$\def\span{\operatorname{span}}$
Let $U,V$ be two subspaces of $R_5$, each of dimension 2. Define the set $W:=U+V$ as the set of all vectors $w=u+v$ where $u\in U$ and $v\in V$. Find all possible values for the dimension of $W$ and explain it.

**My approach:**

Let $U = \{u_1;u_2\}$, $V = \{v_1;v_2\}$ and let $U,V\subseteq \dim(R_5)$. Given $\dim(U)=2$, $\dim(V)=2$ and $\dim(R_5)=5$, I know that $\dim(W)\leq 5$ since $\dim(R_5)=5$, I also know that $\dim(W) = \dim(U) + \dim(V)-\dim(U\cap V)$, and $\dim(U\cap V)\leq 2$ since 2 is the size of the smaller of $U$ and $V$. So possible values for the dimension of $W$ are,

1. $\dim(W) = 2+2-2 = 2$. This happens when $U=V$ since $U\cap V = U\cup V$ (i.e.) $\operatorname{span}\{u_1,u_2,v_1,v_2\} = \span\{u_1,u_2\} = \span\{v_1,v_2\}$
2. $\dim(W) = 2+2-1=3$. This happens when $\dim(\span\{u_1,u_2,v_1,v_2\}) = 3$ (i.e.) there is 1 redundant vector.
3. $\dim(W) = 2+2-0=4$. This happens when $U = \span\{u_1,u_2\}, V = \span\{v_1,v_2\}$ and $\{u_1,u_2,v_1,v_2\}$ are linearly independent.

Therefore, $2\leq \dim(w)< 5$. I'm also curious to know how to reason about the two subspaces in terms of the intersection and union; that is, how do I picture the scenarios geometrically.

Comment: $2+2-2=0$ is a typo. And it's hard to picture things in five dimensions.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it.